# Haskell Instances required for definition

Tags: function, haskell

I have the following Haskell code, a function that checks how many digits are the same in a number and based on how many of them were the same takes a value. I keep getting the error:

> Instances of (Ord (Int -> Int -> Int), Num (Int -> Int -> Int)) required for definition of digits

```
digits :: Int->Int->Int 

digits x y
    |(equal < 2) = 0
    |(equal == 2) = 1
    |(equal == 3) = 5
    |(equal == 4) = 20
    |(equal == 5) = 300
    |(equal == 6) = 8000
    |(equal == 7) = 10000
    |otherwise = 100000
    where
        equal :: Int -> Int -> Int

        equal 0 0 = 0
        equal a b
            |(a `mod` 10 == b `mod` 10) = 1 + equal (a `div` 10) (b `div` 10)
            |otherwise = 1 + equal (a `div` 10) (b `div` 10)
```

What am I doing wrong? Also what does the error mean exactly?

*EDIT*: Did it like this and it works like a charm!

```
digits :: Int->Int->Int 

digits x y
    |(c < 2) = 0
    |(c == 2) = 1
    |(c == 3) = 5
    |(c == 4) = 20
    |(c == 5) = 300
    |(c == 6) = 8000
    |(c == 7) = 10000
    |otherwise = 100000
    where c = equal x y

        where
            equal :: Int -> Int -> Int

            equal 0 0 = 0
            equal a b
                |(a `mod` 10 == b `mod` 10) = 1 + equal (a `div` 10) (b `div` 10)
                |otherwise = 0 + equal (a `div` 10) (b `div` 10)
```

Comment: You are trying to compare a function named `equal` to a variety of `Int` values. Did you perhaps intend to compare the return value of `equal x y` to those values?

Comment: Your two cases for `equal` appear to be identical, by the way: `1 + equal (div a 10) (div b 10)` in either case.

Comment: @chepner Yes the value of equal is exactly what I want to  return. But I thought haskell has no return like other OOP languages like java? Thanks for the correction in the identical code also!

Comment: Note that this can easier be written with `case equal x y of`.